# How do I use the Address formats in i18napis?

Tags: reactjs, formatting, internationalization, format, street-address

I'm am trying to use the [i18napis.appspot.com/address](http://i18napis.appspot.com/address) address formats for a React application so that I can create localized address forms, but it's not clear to me how to use it. 
For example, [this is the info for Germany:](http://i18napis.appspot.com/address/data/DE)

```
{
   zipex: "26133,53225",
   key: "DE",
   zip: "\d{5}",
   fmt: "%N%n%O%n%A%n%Z %C",
   id: "data/DE",
   posturl: "http://www.postdirekt.de/plzserver/",
   require: "ACZ",
   name: "GERMANY"
}
```

The `zip` is a pretty straight forward regex, but how do I use the `fmt: "%N%n%O%n%A%n%Z %C"` format? What are `N` `O` `A` `Z` and `C` in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Google's [`libaddressinput`](https://github.com/google/libaddressinput/wiki/AddressValidationMetadata) documentation,

N - Name

O - Organization

A - Street Address Line(s)

Z - Zip or postal code

C - City or Locality